# How to get grouped Sum with nest in one step

Tags: r, purrr

I am unable to get grouped sum in one single step using nest but in 2 steps. How can I use map to loop over `data` column in the output of `nest()`.  Also suggest a way to include the output column in the existing dataframe.

```r
suppressWarnings(library(tidyverse))
tmp_df <- 
  data.frame(group = rep(c(2L, 1L), each = 5), b = rep(c(-1, 1), each = 5)) 

tmp_df1 = tmp_df %>% group_by(group) %>% nest() #step1
map(tmp_df1$data, sum)  #step 2
#> [[1]]
#> [1] -5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 5
```

I know how to get the sum using group_by.

```r
suppressWarnings(library(tidyverse))
tmp_df <- 
  data.frame(group = rep(c(2L, 1L), each = 5), b = rep(c(-1, 1), each = 5)) 

tmp_df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(b))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   group   sum
#>   <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5
#> 2     2    -5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `c_across`

```
library(dplyr)
tmp_df %>% 
     nest_by(group) %>%
     mutate(sum = sum(c_across(data)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Rowwise:  group
#  group               data   sum
#  <int> <list<tbl_df[,1]>> <dbl>
#1     1            [5 × 1]     5
#2     2            [5 × 1]    -5
```

---

Or just

```
tmp_df %>%
   nest_by(group) %>%
   mutate(sum = sum(data))
```

Comment: Still I could not understand the use of c_across here. I am more comfortable with `tmp_df %>% nest_by(group) %>% mutate(sum = sapply(data, sum))`

Comment: @RamakrishnaS you don't need `c_across` here.  I added that as a general case solution.  Please chekc my update

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `nest` you can try `map_dbl` :

```
library(tidyverse)

tmp_df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(sum = map_dbl(data, ~.x %>% sum))

#  group data               sum
#  <int> <list>           <dbl>
#1     2 <tibble [5 × 1]>    -5
#2     1 <tibble [5 × 1]>     5
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what `~.x` means here.  We already mentioned `data` in the function. Again why `~.x` and another `%>%` in the formula.

Comment: `~` is a formula style syntax which is an alternative to anonymous function, `.x` refers to each individual data that we pass in the function. (Read `?map`). If you have trouble using `%>%` in the function then use `sum(.x)` it works the same way. I used `%>%` for readability purpose but you don't have to use it.